# Wordpress PHP code to display thumbnail and title of children of children's pages

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am working on a custom Wordpress site and need to create code that displays a thumbnail and title of all its child subpages. ie, on its level 1 subpages I am display all their own child pages, but i need the parent page to display all level 3 subpages.

ie

- Level 1 page - NEEDS TO DISPLAY THUMBNAIL + TITLE OF ALL LEVEL 3 PAGES

  - Level 2 page - displays thumbnails and title of all level 3 (DONE)

    - Level 3 page
    - Level 3 page
  - Level 2 page - displays thumbnails and title of all level 3 (DONE)

    - Level 3 page
    - Level 3 page

At the moment I have the following code in the Level 2 pages. How can i tailor this so the parent page (Level 1) of these pages (Level 2) display ALL the level 3 thumbnails and titles? Thanks for any ideas.

```
<!-- INSERT CODE -->
<?php $child_pages = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_parent = ".$post->ID." AND post_type = 'page' ORDER BY menu_order", 'OBJECT');

if ( $child_pages ) :
    foreach ( $child_pages as $pageChild ) :
        setup_postdata( $pageChild );
        $thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($pageChild->ID, 'work-thumb');
        if($thumbnail == "") continue; // Skip pages without a thumbnail
?>
        <div class="child-thumb">
         <p class="thumbnail_img">
         <a href="<?= get_permalink($pageChild->ID) ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?= $pageChild->post_title ?>"><?= $thumbnail ?></a></p>
         <h3><a href="<?= get_permalink($pageChild->ID) ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?= $pageChild->post_title ?>"><?= $pageChild->post_title ?></a></h3>
        </div>
<?
    endforeach;
endif;
?>

<!-- FINISH CODE -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Right have found a solution using this.

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/displaying-children-content-on-parent-page?replies=10